# Introducing delay in displaying a message . transition-delay property not working

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have the following div tag which contains an up arrow.If hovered upon it displays a message.
I want a one second delay in bringing up that message. I used transition-delay property but its not working.
(Note- I have kept the css as inline purposely for demonstration purpose.).
Also can it be done using Angularjs?
Any help would be appreciated.

```
<div class="col-xs-1" style="margin-left:-40px;">
     <div class="arrow-up" ng-mouseover="message_up = true" ng-mouseleave="message_up= false" ng-click="saveVote(review[0].review_id,1);"></div>
     <div class="message" ng-show="message_up" style="width:180px;position:absolute;margin-left:10px; margin-top:15px; background-color:#333;text-align:center;z-index:1001;color:white;transition-delay: 3s;">This review is helpful and clear.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

what is the property that you want the transition delay to happen? since you said that you wnat the message to just appear after a time period... i created a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/ZMc2S/

all i did added an opacity value for the message div and gave the

```
transition-property: opacity
```

hope this helps